# I'm being billed and I don't know how to stop it

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud, djangoappengine, gae-quotas

How can I check all the services I'm making use of on app engine. I'm being billed and I don't know how to stop it. I've lost about $15. And I don't know where it's coming from

Comment: Delete the app would the charge. There's billing information that you can check to see the breakdown of the charge

Comment: I've checked it. Seems app engine flexible environment is kinda difficult to use for newbies. If you're not careful, you'll incur too much charges. That's not nice

Answer (score 0):

Alright this is how I solved mine:

I disabled billing to ensure that I wasn't incurring anymore charges, then I checked my transaction log to view what was costing me much. App engine flexible environment does not currently support zero instance scaling so we're stuck with having at least one instance at all times